# Parseval's equivalent of Norm that includes a Projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, fourier-transform, conservation-laws, stochastic-filtering

I need to optimize the norm, ${\bf x}^H {\bf P}_{\bf B} {\bf x}  $, where, ${\bf P}_{\bf B} = {\bf B}^H({\bf B} {\bf B}^H)^{-1} {\bf B}$, ${\bf B}$ is a known $M \times N$ matrix, with $M < N$ and $rank({\bf B}) = M$.

The optimization is w.r.t $\bf x$ with the constraint ${\bf x}^H{\bf v}=1$, where $\bf v$ is a Vandermonde vector. The constraint is equivalent to the Fourier Transform of ${\bf x} = \|X(f)\| $ =1. The solution to this optimization is known in the time (or spatial) domain.  I want to analyze it in the frequency domain, if possible.

I would like to convert this norm to the frequency-domain using Parseval's Theorem so that I can use the filtering interpretation of the Projection operator, ${\bf P}_{\bf B}$.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The matrix $P_B$ is the orthogonal projection onto the rows of $B$, so the optimal value of $x^H P_B x$ is simply equal $1$ (assuming you're optimizing over unit vectors $x$). Is there additional context here that I'm missing?

Comment: I have updated my question by adding context. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "Optimize" is rather vague. Do you mean "minimize"? And which norm?

Comment: I want to minimize using the $\ell_2$ norm. I am not looking for the solution of the minimization in the time domain. An equivalent frequency domain representation, especially for the quadratic form that includes the projection matrix would be beneficial for my study. Thanks.